# How to interpret « vous voyez comme je suis au courant ! »

Tags: sens

> X : Vous vous êtes disputés ?
>
> Y : Non.
>
> X : Non ? Eh bien, vous voyez **comme** je suis au courant ! J’étais persuadé que vous aviez eu des mots !

I wonder if « comme » is used for emphasis purposes here and the sentence as a whole is intended as an ironic turn of phrase?

Also, I’m curious about the nuances of meaning between « comme je suis au courant ! » and « vous voyez comme je suis au courant ! ».

Comment: It's really hard to say whether it's meant sarcastically without more context. Secondly I don't see particular emphasis here, can you give an example of a sentence that you feel had the same meaning but would be less emphatic?

Comment: It seems to be ironic. Here "comme" means "à quel point" ("how much").

Comment: @qoba Hi. I cannot recall the exact subsequent sentence, but I think it was something like this one. (Edited)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is definitely irony in the second sentence. X is actually telling (s)he is (actually was) unaware of their relationship.

> You didn't? Well, that shows how much I'm aware of it! I was convinced you quarreled!

Dropping *vous voyez* would make the sentence less intelligible, a possible alternative might be:

> *Non ? Eh bien, je suis au courant maintenant ! J’étais persuadé que vous aviez eu des mots !*

Answer (score 1):

Here "*Comme je suis [thing]*" is "how [thing] I am". You can tell because of "*tu as vu*".

It also works with *avoir* :

> *Tu as vu comme j'ai progressé ?* = Have you seen how much I've improved ?

It's hard to translate "*être au courant*" in a short way so it looks similar in english. I'd say it's something like :

> "You see how aware I am of what's happening between you two ? I was certain you argued !"

---

About your last part, using "*comme*" alone (in the beginning of a sentence) means you're impressed by something, it's an exclamation.

> Comme c'est beau ! = It's so beautiful !

A more casual say of saying is with "comment":  "*Comment j'ai faim !*" = "Man, I'm hungry"

"*Comme*" can also express a cause, if it's accompanied by the consequence.

> *Comme vous me dites jamais rien, je sais pas si vous vous disputez ou pas*.
>
> You never tell me anything, so I don't know if you argue or not.